# SpriteKit - more than 32 collision layers? Nonvisual simulation of engine?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, collision-detection, game-physics

new to 2D sprite systems. I have an evolving neural network I want to test in a visual environment (for example, having two space fighters fly around at each other with momentum, with the learning AI fighting a static AI).

Looking into SpriteKit, and the momentum and collision physics work great. However, the genetic algorithm will have 100+ members per population, and each "fight" lasts 10+ seconds. This starts taking a long time when talking about simulating out a large number of generations.

- Speeding up the world: Accelerating the PhysicsWorld reduces the amount of time the AI is able to 'think,' which can break the simulation (a normal run has 400 frames/update() calls before one bot hits the other; doubling the simulation speed, there's roughly 200 calls, and the behavior can be slightly different). **Is there a way to speed up the simulation (increase speed and FPS) in SpriteKit? Or better yet, a way to run the simulation in the background without having to build my own physics engine?**
- I thought about running all the fighters simultaneously, with collisions only operating for players/enemies on the same "layer." It looks like SpriteKit only allows 32 such layers simultaneously -- **Is there a way I could bump the number of collision layers up to run the whole generation simultaneously**? I know I could add in new fighters as each of the 32 resolves if necessary, but this may still be slower than running it all at once.
- Any way to switch SpriteKit to a tick-based time system, where each run of update() simulates the passage of X seconds? Same problem of update() limiting itself to 60 FPS, but this gets me a step closer. This kills the battery.
- **Is there an alternate sprite library that would be better suited to what I'm trying to do**? I've debated just building it myself, but would prefer a library since this is just a test of the network, not an end to itself.

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to look into using the Metal framework. I don't know much about the implementation of it etc... but it's a much lower level framework allowing you access to low level apis that you can use to boost performance of things like games. It would require a lot of work AFAIK.

Comment: Just to add... it may be possible to exploit Metal to do some heavy lifting for you while still using Sprite Kit. Maybe that might be worth looking into.

Comment: @Fogmeister - yeah, I considered looking at Metal, but seemed like a crazy learning curve for something that feels basic, either running spritekit with the physics world accelerated and update() called at max processor speed (running the simulation as fast as possible in the background, or a tick-based simulation instead of time-based, with each tick equalling X amount of time...) or only having ally/enemy-pairs interact with each other and run them all at once.

Comment: You do not need all 32 layers, From what I am understanding, you only need 2.  You use different categories when the behavior is different,so  using all 32 only slows the process down (instead of checking 2 pools, it needs to check 32 pools).  If you want to speed things up, then you need to reduce the number of checks that happen, so you may want to base your categories on what quadrants the sprites are in.  An example would be since we know the top left sprites will never hit the bottom right sprites, there is no need to check physics for contact, so we set these 2 in a different quadrant

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Each enemy and ally will be on a single collision layer. To grow the AI, they need to start with the same relative {X,Y} arrangement. You're right, I could place them far enough apart  that they likely won't interact, but that presents a visualization problem. Ideally all 100 allies and enemies could be started on top of each other, though you're right that the collision system may be too slow to handle that. Ideally, I would be able to set all the sprites on different Z levels (with no ability to move on the Z axis), but AFAIK spritekit doesn't do that.

Comment: yeah the system at hand is not designed to handle such large amounts of sprites,  you need to resort to tricks to help filter out needless checks, like in cases where 1 over laps 2 fully, and 2 overlaps 3 fully, then 1 does not need to check that it overlaps 3 because we know it does